# Can you collect the page depth by page using Google Analytics API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

In GA you're able to see data for landing pages and second pages (the second page viewed in a session) as well as the conversion rates associated with it.

Are you able or legally allowed to collect the 3rd/4th/5th page viewed in a session as a custom dimension? If so how would you write the code for a custom dimension.

Example data: the /shop page of a website had 300 pageviews as 2nd page, 700 pageviews as the 3rd page, 100 pageviews as the 4th page, etc.

Comment: I cant see why you would think that you would not legal be allowed to record data.  The only data you cant record is personal identifiable information like emails.    You might want to check out the mfc api it may be close to what you are looking for.

Comment: The google-analytics-sdk tag is for the mobile developement kits (Android and iOs) - is that relevant here ?

Comment: @EikePierstorff you're right, my apologies. tag removed

Comment: @DaImTo I wasn't sure if it was against any of the new cookie policy laws or something. And thank you, I'll look into that API